# Formatting .readLine output for currency and right aligned

Tags: vb.net

I am writing a simple program that writes input to a sequential access file and then reads them back and displays them in the list box using .readLine. The numbers need to be formatted for american currency and right aligned.  Problem is i cant figure out how to properly write the .readLine to do that.  **i am working out of a text book, and still new to vb.net, so im looking for the simplest way to solve this problem without re-writing alot of it.**  **The code i have tried is within the DO loop below:**

```
Private Sub btnDisplay_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnDisplay.Click
    'declare new inFile Varable as a streamreader object
    Dim inFile As IO.StreamReader
    'opens gross.txt for input
    inFile = IO.File.OpenText("gross.txt")
    '.Exists() searches /bin folder for gross.txt, returns a boolean value
    If IO.File.Exists("gross.txt") Then
        inFile = IO.File.OpenText("gross.txt")
        'fill the list with the values
        Do Until inFile.Peek = -1
            lstContents.Items.Add(inFile.ReadLine.PadLeft(7, " ")).ToString("C2")
        Loop
    Else
        MessageBox.Show("The file you have requested does not exist", "Gross Pay Project",
                        MessageBoxButtons.OKCancel, MessageBoxIcon.Error)
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: It would help if you showed some sample input, desired result and actual result. However, I suspect you need to convert to currency format and *then* pad left. (Also, you have a redundant `inFile = IO.File.OpenText("gross.txt")` before checking if that file exists, and you have forgotten to give a full path to the file.)

Comment: by default it looks in the bin/debug directory, and thats where the file is located, so there is no issue there.  I tried switching pad left and ToString to no avail.

Comment: If your textbook told you to use the .Exists() method, ignore that part. .Exists() only checks one reason a file might not open. It ignores file permissions and process locking. Even when checking whether a file exists, the file system is volatile and you still have a race condition situation. It's almost always better to just skip calling File.Exists() and instead use a try/catch block to handle an exception if opening the file fails.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can get this down to a single line:

```
lstContents.Items.AddRange(File.ReadAllLines("gross.txt").Select(Function(s) Double.Parse(s).ToString("C2").PadLeft(7)).ToArray())
```

Or in a more readable way, with the error-handling and method defintion back:

```
Private Sub btnDisplay_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnDisplay.Click
    Try
        lstContents.Items.AddRange( _
            File.ReadAllLines("gross.txt").
                    Select(Function(s) Decimal.Parse(s).ToString("C2").PadLeft(7)).
                    ToArray()  )
    Catch ex As IOException
         MessageBox.Show("Unable to open the file you requested", "Gross Pay Project",
                        MessageBoxButtons.OKCancel, MessageBoxIcon.Error)
    End Try
End Sub
```

---

Now to explain this code. To begin with, I replaced your call to `IO.File.Exists()` with a `Try`/`Catch` block. `File.Exists()` only checks one reason a file might not open. It ignores other reasons like file permissions and process locking. Even when checking whether a file exists, the file system is volatile and you still have a race condition situation, where a file might be deleted in between when you check if it exists and when you go to open it. It's almost always better to just skip calling `File.Exists()` entirely and instead use the try/catch block to handle an exception if opening the file fails, as shown above.

Going into the Try/Catch block, I changed the code so that it uses `AddRange()` instead of adding one item at a time in a loop. This allows us to build an array with the items we want and update the UI in a single step. Building that array may seem like extra work, but .Net provides some features to help us. In this case, the `File.ReadAllLines()` method reads in the entire file in one step, so that we can start with an array right from the beginning. All we have to do is make the array have the right information.

To get the information we want in the array, I perform a *projection* or *transformation* of the existing data. To accomplish that, I used a LINQ select operator (or the `.Select()` extension method, in this case). The LINQ extension methods generally ask you to build an inline function. In the case of this use of the select operator, that inline function expects a string variable (`s`) that represents a single line in the original array. I then supply code to transform that original string into the format we need.

Each line in the file begins as a string value, but we know that the string variable holds pricing information... it will be numeric. The best way to transform numeric data is generally to convert it a number, which is what I do. I chose the `Decimal` type, because when working with money you almost always want to prefer Decimal over Double or Single. In this case, Double may have been okay, but Decimal will still work just fine. Once I have a numeric type like Decimal, I can use a [Numeric Format String](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dwhawy9k%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) to get a string back that has the correct currency symbol and formatting. The original code did not work because you were trying to use the format string with a value that was already a string type. The format strings only work with numeric types, like the Decimal we have here. Now that I have a string with the correct text, all I need to do now is pad it so that it will be right-justified when shown in the list.

Finally, you will recall that the AddRange() method expects an array. The LINQ select operator does not produce an array. It produces something called an `IEnumerable`. This is a type that represents a sequence of some kind. Arrays are one kind of sequence, but they are not the *only* kind of sequence, and the LINQ system wants to be able to work with many different kinds of sequences. Thankfully, getting back to an array is easy: just call the `ToArray()` method.

Comment: thanks for the answer, but can this be done just by re-writing my Do loop with simpler code?  I am new to vb.net and im afraid don't understand how your code works.

Comment: @musicman_385 Good for you in learning to code. However, I don't want to get you into bad habits, so instead I've added an explanation of how this code works.

Comment: however i am getting 2 errors, *IOException not defined*, and *File is not declared*.

Comment: @musicman_385 Please put `Imports System.IO` at the top of the file (after any `Option` lines if applicable).

Answer (score 0):

You should definitely use a ListView instead of a listbox.  I don't think you can right-align with listbox items.

Comment: i would do that but the text book file has a list box, so i assume i should use that for now until i learn listview :-)